# how to call two apis in one typeahead selection

Tags: angularjs

I am using the angular typeahead:-

```
<label>USER</label>
     <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="a.user" autocomplete="off" typeahead="a for a in getAllUsers($viewValue);getAllStaffs($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingCodes" typeahead-no-results="noResults">
```

My directive Code:-

```
scope.getAllUsers = function(key) {
    var obj = {
        "key": key
    }
    if (key.length >= 2) {
        return ApiServices.getAllUsers(obj).then(function(response) {
            return response.data.map(function(item) {
                return item;
            });
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

scope.getAllStaffs = function(key) {
    var obj = {
        "key": key
    }
    if (key.length >= 2) {
        return ApiServices.getAllStaffs(obj).then(function(response) {
            return response.data.map(function(item) {
                return item;
            });
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

There are two functions:- One is used for fetching users name and one is used for fetching staffs name. I want both this functions to call on the same input.
But the typeahead is getting list of staff members only. Is there any way to get both list populated in the same input.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you never accepted any of the answer on your previous questions (I didn't downvoted BTW)

Comment: Alton Eitan, I do accept the answers, if they are able to help me in anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function that does both requests and merges the results.

```
scope.getAllNames = function(key) {
    var obj = {
        "key": key
    }

    function extract(resp) {
        return resp.data.slice(0)
    }
    if (key.length >= 2) {
        return Promise.all([
          ApiServices.getAllUsers(obj).then(extract), 
          ApiServices.getAllStaffs(obj).then(extract)
        ])
        .then(function(results) {
            return [].concat.apply([], results) 
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yury Tarabanko, I keep getting error getAllStaffs(obj) is not a function, Are u sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: @shreyagupta This is how it was named in your code `ApiServices.getAllStaffs` LOL